# File output was overwritten using tee within Bash Shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I was trying to learn how `exec` and `tee` work and encountered something I could not understand:

```
# create a log.out file in current directory
log=$(echo $(pwd)/log.out)

# start redirect
# 3 holds stdout, 4 holds stderr
# 1 & 2 points to log.out
exec 3>&1 4>&2 &>${log}

# print 'Have a good day everyone!' to both log.out and stdout 
echo 'Have a good day everyone!' | tee ${log} 1>&3
echo 'Ciao!'
echo 'Bye!'

# end redirect
exec 1>&3 2>&4 3>&- 4>&-
```

When I went into log.out file, I got this:

```
Ciao!                                                                                                                                                 
Bye!                                                                                                                                                  
 day everyone!
```

I was expecting:

```
Have a good day everyone!
Ciao!
Bye!
```

Please help me understand what is going on here and how to resolve this.

Thank you.

If this is duplicate, please close and give me the link to the solution.

Comment: As an aside, `log=$PWD/log.out` would be a more performant and less error-prone way to do the assignment (if your current directory name contains a whitespace-surrounded wildcard, the output from that `echo` could be... surprising -- and creating a subshell just to run the `pwd` command in is a fair bit of overhead).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It is very nice! I am a beginner in Shell. Could you please recommend some good places to learn best practices in Shell?

Comment: The bash-hackers wiki at http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/ and the Wooledge wiki (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) are reliably high-quality resources. It's also worth making a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and reading the documentation linked in anything it finds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening here is that while `tee` is adding content to your file, the existing open file pointer created by `exec &>log.out` is still back at the beginning of that file. Thus, when you start writing to that file pointer, those writes start at the beginning, despite other contents having been written by `tee`.

---

If you want to ensure that content is always added to the end of the file, even if other software has modified *where* that end-of-the-file location *is*, then you should ensure that the `O_APPEND` flag is used on open.

To do this, use `>>` rather than `>` for your redirection:

```
exec 3>&1 4>&2 &>>${log}
```